# Android. Google map API implement on marker click

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api, marker

I use google places API to search nearby hospitals. I need to display a custom dialog with the information that I received in the request of the nearest hospitals by clicking on the marker. But in the `onMarkerClick(Marker marker)` method there is only such information about the marker as title, position etc. But I need to show also the address, photo and other parameters from nearby hospitals request, how can this be implemented.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code on how you are calling Places Nearby Search?

Comment: Just create custom wrapper for default `Marker` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an info window to display place information using the marker's `snippet` property upon clicking on a marker, like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows#add_an_info_window):

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(MELBOURNE)
                          .title("Melbourne")
                          .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"));
```

Replace the hard-coded string with the place's information retrieved from nearby search that you want to display. You can also do:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), marker.getSnippet(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   return false;
}
```

There are multiple ways to achieve this but this would be the easiest. You're also able to [customize](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows#custom_info_windows) the info windows' content using `getInfoContents()`.